# Experience with Revive Add-Server integration

Tags: flutter

We have an existing Flutter based mobile application, pulling advertising content from our own CMS, using REST API's and Cloudinary as the CDN.

We are considering moving our campaign content on to the hosted Revive Add-Server platform, however I am not seeing any Flutter plugins to support this functionality.

Revive provides 3 methods of embedding tags into a website:

Asynchronous JS Tag:

```
<!-- Revive Adserver Hosted edition Asynchronous JS Tag - Generated with Revive Adserver v5.3.1 -->
    <ins data-revive-zoneid="12330" data-revive-id="727bec5e09208690b050ccfc6a45d384"></ins>
    <script async src="//servedby.revive-adserver.net/asyncjs.php"></script>
```

Javascript tag:

```
<!-- Revive Adserver Hosted edition Javascript Tag - Generated with Revive Adserver v5.3.1 -->
<script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
   var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://servedby.revive-adserver.net/ajs.php':'http://servedby.revive-adserver.net/ajs.php');
   var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
   if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("?zoneid=12330");
   document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
   if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
   document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
   document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
   if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
   if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
   document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>--></script><noscript><a href='http://servedby.revive-adserver.net/ck.php?n=a4b4d08e&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://servedby.revive-adserver.net/avw.php?zoneid=12330&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=a4b4d08e' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>
```

iFrame Tag:

```
<!-- Revive Adserver Hosted edition iFrame Tag - Generated with Revive Adserver v5.3.1 -->
<iframe id='a63933d6' name='a63933d6' src='http://servedby.revive-adserver.net/afr.php?zoneid=12330&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='468' height='60' allow='autoplay'><a href='http://servedby.revive-adserver.net/ck.php?n=ae1d1118&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://servedby.revive-adserver.net/avw.php?zoneid=12330&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=ae1d1118' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>
```

We are currently displaying video and banner content content outside of a browser interface.
I was wondering if anyone could share any integration experience.

Ideally we would want to access the individual data components of image, click through URL and text, and display these as per normal, without too much redesign of our current UX, without having to resort to a browser or iFrame.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP programmer should be able to build a simple plugin which could serve the ad components as separated JSON.